# ReSharper stops working

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, resharper

Running solution with VB.NET & C#, ASP.NET, VS 2008 with ReSharper 5

Most of the time, ReSharper is working (redundant code grayed out, squiggles, etc.)
Sometimes, on the same code where it was working, nothing is highlighted to show ReSharper is enabled.
I haven't done anything except modify code and debug.

What is going on that turns it on/off?

Comment: How large are your source files, and how long have you waited for ReSharper to respond?

Comment: code behind files are several hundred lines.  When it works, it's instant; when it doesn't, I wait up to 5-10min (since I'm adding new code anyway).

Comment: Does closing the code-file and re-opening it fix the problem?

Comment: closing the file didn't, but restarting VS did.

Comment: Sounds like a bug.  Did you upgrade to 5.1?  I'm always having to restart RS in VS 2010.

Comment: 2GB RAM...haven't upgraded to 5.1...will try that.

Comment: Resharper recommends at least 4GB of RAM.  Sounds like time for an upgrade.